# How do I check the last integer in the file in C?

Tags: c

I need some help in finding the last integer in the file for my program. I have a file called "sample.txt" and I have a bunch of numbers in the file so I just want to get the last integer in the file and for example print it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you post sample.txt file contents?

Comment: Integers consist of digits, so I would start by writing code to find the last digit in the file.

Comment: See [ask] and post the code you have a problem with in a [mcve].

Comment: Do you mean the biggest instead the last ?

Comment: Yea but how do I do that? And the text file should be like this " 1 3 77 123 55" And I meant the last.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far. This is not a place to just have ode written for you.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming that you are looking for the `biggest integer` from a list of integers suplied by a input file.

The solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    int ret = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int max = 0;

    pf = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    if(!pf)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        ret = fscanf( pf, "%d", &n );

        if( ret != 1 )
            break;

        if( n > max )
            max = n;
    }

    fclose(pf);

    printf( "The biggest number in the file is: %d\n", max );

    return 0;
}

/* eof *
```

Compiling:

```
$ gcc -Wall numbers.c -o numbers
```

Input File:

```
$ cat input.txt
10 4 30 123 7 3 9 34 61 99
```

Testing:

```
$ ./numbers input.txt
The biggest number in the file is: 123
```

**2)** Assuming that you are looking for the `last integer` from a list of integers suplied by a input file.

The Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    pf = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

    if(!pf)
    {
        printf("Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fscanf( pf, "%d", &n ) == 1);

    fclose(pf);

    printf( "The last number in the file is: %d\n", n );

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Compiling:

```
$ gcc -Wall numbers2.c -o numbers2
```

Input File:

```
$ cat input.txt
10 4 30 123 7 3 9 34 61 99
```

Testing:

```
$ ./numbers2 input.txt
The last number in the file is: 99
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Read the file and scan the tokens.

**sample.txt**

> 0 1 23 2134   123 12321
>
> 123
>
> 42

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    int x;
    while (fscanf(fp, " %d", &x) == 1) { }
    printf("Last integer is %d.\n", x);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Output

```
$ ./a.out 
Last integer is 42.
```

Finding the maximum integer is trivial:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    int x, max=0;
    while (fscanf(fp, " %d", &x) == 1) {
        if(x>max)
            max=x;
    }
    printf("The maximum integer is %d.\n", max);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: 1) Check the result of `fopen`. 2) Why an array? You declare an array of int of size 1024 and use just the first slot. 3) You tell `fscanf` to scan a maximum of 1023 digits into `x[0]`. But 1023 digits is tooooo much for an `int` to handle!

Comment: @CoolGuy I tried improving the code a little. Do you agree now?